# JMS значение null

Tags: weblogic, jms

Пытаюсь реализовать `jms` сервис на `Weblogic`, на `JSP` страничке сделал обычный `input` и когда какой то текст отправляю она приходить на `WEBLOGIC` но почему то `Value = null`.

```
<form action="ProduceMessage">
        Enter the jms message : <input name="myinput" type="text"/>
          <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

а это **Servlet**

```
TextMessage txmsg = session.createTextMessage();
            publisher.send(txmsg);
            con.close();
            System.out.println("msgText="+txmsg.getText());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методом тыка нашел ответ, на `Servlet`-e

```
String myinput=request.getParameter("myinput");
                txmsg.setText(myinput);
```

и все теперь `Value` не `null`.